# Fetch only those array elements in mongodb that satisfy the condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have below test collection in MongoDB:

```
[
  {name: "vipul",arr:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]},
  {name: "rahul",arr:[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},
]
```

Now if I do below query:

```
db.test.find({"arr":{$gt: 5});
```

The above query returns the below output:

```
[
  {name: "vipul",arr:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]},
  {name: "rahul",arr:[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},
]
```

But I need only those elements that match the condition, like below:

```
[
  {name: "vipul",arr:[6,7,8]},
  {name: "rahul",arr:[6,7,8,9,10]},
]
```

I know this can be done using aggregation, but I want to do it without aggregation. Is there any method to do it??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `$filter` for the `arr` field in the projection.

```
db.collection.find({
  "arr": {
    $gt: 5
  }
},
{
  "name": 1,
  "arr": {
    $filter: {
      input: "$arr",
      cond: {
        $gt: [
          "$$this",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZSAGRGUUqv)